# iOS NSMutableArray Memory Leak

Tags: objective-c

I'm having a bit of trouble with memory leaks in my objective c code. Could anyone take a look and let me know what they think?

NSStringArray.h

```
@interface NSStringArray : NSObject {

NSMutableArray *realArray;

}

@property (nonatomic, assign) NSMutableArray *realArray;

-(id)init;
-(void)dealloc;
@end
```

NSStringArray.m

```
#import "NSStringArray.h"


@implementation NSStringArray

@synthesize realArray;

-(id)init {

self = [super init];
if ( self != nil ) {
    realArray = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] retain];
}
return self;
}

-(void)dealloc {
[realArray release];
realArray = nil;
[super dealloc];
}
```

Factory.m

```
+(NSStringArray *)getFields:(NSString *)line {
//Divides the lines into input fields using "," as the separator.
//Returns the separate fields from a given line.  Strips out quotes & carriage returns.

line = [line stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@""];
line = [line stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\r" withString:@""];

NSStringArray *fields = [[NSStringArray alloc] init];

for (NSString *field in [line componentsSeparatedByString:@","]) {
    [fields.realArray addObject:field];
    [field release];    
}

return [fields autorelease];
}
```

The Leaks tool is saying that the leak occurs when fields is allocated, and when I am adding field string to the fields array.

Also, this function is getting called each line of a file that I'm parsing.

Any tips would be helpful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this piece of code, you break the memory management rules.

```
for (NSString *field in [line componentsSeparatedByString:@","]) {
    [fields.realArray addObject:field];
    [field release];    
}
```

You do not own the object pointed at by `field` so you must not release it.

You have overreleased field so the last object to release it (the autorelease pool in your case) is releasing an already dealloc'd object.

Comment: That was the problem! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4):

This line does a double retain:

```
realArray = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] retain];
```

it is enough

```
realArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Comment: That is what I thought as well, but when I take out the retain the application crashes with EXEC_BAD_ACCESS.

Comment: @Erik Rodriguez: Then you have a problem elsewhere.

Comment: This is correct (+1), but see my answer for why you get the crash when you leave out the retain.

Answer (score 2):

From [the docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaObjects/CocoaObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH4-SW54):

> An allocation message does other important things besides allocating
>   memory:
>
> - It sets the object’s retain count to one (as described in “How Memory
>     Management Works”).

Therefore, you don't need to retain something that you've just alloc'ed.

Comment: That is what I thought as well, but when I take out the retain the application crashes with EXEC_BAD_ACCESS. It looks like when the autorelease pool is released is when it crashes.

Comment: That's because you're releasing something that you shouldn't. Please read @JeremyP's answer, and then read the [Memory Management Rules](http://tinyurl.com/6ktdglb).

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Felz answer above. Use self.realArray when allocating array

```
self.realArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Because you have created a property for the array so it is better to use "**self**"

Answer (score 1):

You could also take advantage of the properties in objective C to make
more clear and efficient your code:

NSStringArray.h

```
@interface NSStringArray : NSObject {
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *realArray;
@end
```

NSStringArray.m

```
#import "NSStringArray.h"

@implementation NSStringArray

@synthesize realArray = _realArray;

-(id)init {

self = [super init];
if (self) {
    self.realArray = [NSMutableArray array];
}
return self;
}

-(void)dealloc {
[_realArray release];
[super dealloc];
}
```

Now, with the modifier `retain` of the property realArray you can use 
`[NSMutableArray array]` that return an autorelease mutable array.

The retain properties manage the retain/release stuff by themselves.

You don't need to use the `realArray = nil;` line. You've already deallocated
the property.

Hope this can help.

Comment: Excellent excellent advice! I'm still quite new to objective-c and any best practices are very much welcomed! Thanks!